# How to delete list elements in a loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to create a list in a `for-loop` which is updated every step `i=1:200`.

In my case, in each step `i` I require the list elements `i+1` and `i+2`, nothing more.

I would ultimately end up with a list of length 202, which I expect to considerably slow down my calculation (about 1 hour for 200 steps currently).

In order to shorten the list, I want to delete each list element `i` that I don't need (i.e. all i=i).

Unfortunately, I tried to simply delete list elements in the `for-loop` using 
`mylist[[i]]<-NULL` or `mylist<-mylist[-i]`. Both work fine outside a loop, but not inside the loop. Here a brief example:

```
mylist<-list()
for (i in 1:3){
  mylist[[i+1]]<-c(1:10)*i
  mylist[[i]]<-NULL}
mylist

mylist<-list()
for (i in 1:3){
  mylist[[i+1]]<-c(1:10)*i
  mylist<-mylist[-i]}
mylist
mylist[[i]]<-NULL
mylist<-mylist[-i]
```

Comment: _"In my case, in each step i I require the list elements i+1 and i+2"_, but you start with an empty list? Do you need future elements, or only two iterations in the past? I don't understand how your example matches the description. Could you just maintain a list of length two? What is the expected output?

Comment: So your main output that you're interested in is only the last element of the list?

Comment: @Axeman: Thanks for the response. The example is a very simplified version to show the problem. In my case I start in i=1, creating mylist[[i]], which is used to determine mylist[[i+1]] and mylist[[i+2]] (all created at step i). I need to use mylist[[i+1]] in next step (i+1) and mylist[[i+2]] at step i+2. However, each step i I need to update mylist[[i]], mylist[[i+1]] and mylist[[i+2]], but at the same time have the lists from previous 2 steps available. The output is a matrix or data.frame with varying rows and 4 columns. Not sure whether this is feasible. Might have to overthink. Thanks.

Comment: @tobiasegli_te: Thanks for the reply. I need the last two elements of the list created in each step i, which are implemented in steps i+1 and i+2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would setting to `NA` work for you?

```
mylist<-list()
for (i in 1:100){
  mylist[[i+1]]<-c(1:10)*i
  mylist[[i+2]]<-c(11:20)*i
  mylist[[i]] <- NA
}
mylist
# [[1]]
# [1] NA
# ...
# [[100]]
# [1] NA
#
# [[101]]
# [1]  100  200  300  400  500  600  700  800  900 1000
#
# [[102]]
# [1] 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does help to reduce the size of mylist to some extent. I will give it a go.

Comment: To get rid of the NAs just do mylist[!is.na(mylist)]

Comment: Good suggestion, but does not seem to work within the loop. But setting mylist[[i]] <- NA (as you suggested) does help to reduce processing time. I am wondering whether using an array instead of a list would be a better idea in terms of speed? Thanks

Comment: You have to remove the NAs after the loop is finished. Whether to use an array or a list depends on what you're doing and what the result is in each iteration, but it shouldn't affect the speed (with 200 iterations). Maybe you could optimize whatever you're doing in each iteration to speed the loop up.